# Minecraft only allows me to play offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc, minecraft-launcher

I saw another question like this, but none of the answers seemed to work, so here is my situation.

My computer is getting Internet. I am asking this question from the same PC, so I clearly have a working Internet connection. When I open Minecraft, the launcher comes up and then just says "Play Offline". How can I play online? Is something blocking it? Any help would be appreciated!

This happens when playing from my PC and my gameband when plugged into my PC!

#### Update

My entire firewall is now disabled, but it is still doing this. All errors say to check the firewall and allow Minecraft through, but it is disabled (and even if it wasn't, it allows both Minecraft and Java TM SE Binary).

I am starting to think it may be malware. Any ideas for finding any malware programs that block Internet use (if they exist)?

Comment: You probably aren't logged into your account. Is there a "Sign In" button or something similar in the bottom corner?

Comment: @NickB. what is that other question? Could it be you're behind a VPN or proxy? (Eliminating common problems)

Comment: **Windows** Firewall might be disabled, but what about antivirus programs with their own firewall? Some of them (Norton IIRC) even *leave their firewall running* after you disable the entire application. What antivirus software do you have installed, and does it have any settings related to the firewall?

Comment: @Robotnik lol, too many Nick's for one post. Anyways, I don't have any antivirus that I know about. I have norton account, but I haven't gotten it for this PC yet. I am running a malwarebytes scan now to see if it might be maleware.

Comment: Make sure your router or ISP does not block the mojang auth servers. While all ISP's should have it as a trusted address, checking if so just narrows it down.

Answer (score 5):

### You must be signed in to play online.

If you have a legitimate version of Minecraft then it should prompt you to sign in upon launch.

You can try checking your firewall to make sure your computer is not blocking the internet connectivity of the application.

Comment: I am logged in, I knew that, but now when I went to multiplayer (When playing offline), it says would you like to keep blocking or unblock... When I click unblock, I guess it unblocked it, but I still could not play online. When I try to login(just to test), it says cannot connect to mojang auth servers!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You said at the beginning of your comment you are logged in, but at the end of the comment you said you tried to login and it wouldn't connect. So you were already logged in and playing online before? Or is this the first time you've tried playing on this PC?

Comment: What happened is I was somehow logged in, but online was not working (I have played on this PC before). I decided to try and log out and relog to see what would happen. When I tried to relog it said cannot connect to auth servers.

Comment: Okay so it sounds like your computer might be blocking the internet connectivity of the application. Here are the instructions to check it on Windows: Go to Control Panel, find and open Windows Firewall. At the left click on "Allow a program through Windows Firewall". Click the "Add Program" tab which will bring up a list of all the programs on your system. Find Minecraft, click the box to check it, click OK, then Apply and finally OK to close.

Comment: That's what I though too, but everything marked as either Minecraft or Java a TM SE Binary is allowed through public and private networks!

Comment: I mean, is it possible that Minecraft servers are down?

Comment: I just tried logging in and it worked for me. Status websites are saying it's online. Try running "tracert minecraft.net" in cmd if you can and see what that says.

Comment: Read the end of the question again, I added an edit!

Comment: Malware Bytes is good for cleaning up computers. What happened when you tried "tracert minecraft.net" in command line?

Comment: Some requests got a response, but many said timed out ("Are those requests or what?") when I ran that command.

Comment: Okay so you are able to connect to minecraft's servers then. Must be an issue with app internet connectivity. You said you have played online with this PC before. How long ago was that?

Comment: Well, I guess like a little over 5 day ago

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you do need to wait up to 20 seconds. You should see the launch button switch from Play Offline to Play.

Have you tried changing where the gameband is plugged in, I know it sounds stupid but sometimes it works

Hope this helps and have fun gaming!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, also checking with your host or **the host** and see if the server has "Online Mode = True" or not. That would be on the person whos hosting the server "server.properties" file. That can also be looked at to see if thats 1 reason, other then you logging in or just checking your firewall ports, however the firewall ports are usually taken care of once you log in to minecraft connecting to a world, your firewall should pop up and ask you "Accept or Not Accept." Those are the only 3 possibilities thats preventing you from logging in. It **WILL** be one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try

- uninstalling your Minecraft
- then heading to %appdata%\Roaming.minecraft\
- Nine times out of ten, that .minecraft folder will still be there, its safe to delete it, however with that being said, I hold no responsibility should you delete your favorite mods. If you have files you want to save and not delete, just rename that **.minecraft** folder to **.minecraftBACKUP**
- Last step is to reinstall Minecraft again, it should solve your problem, if it does not, then you need to trace back the steps We all told you about back in https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/348599/229636

Good luck, it's an almost guarantee that out of everything stated here and from what others have told you, somethings gotta work, if not, your not paying attention to any details during your installation or even the instructions from Minecraft, as you should, just in case you happen to miss the firewall rules. Please, let us know the outcome if should it work :) That helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem recently, and I have worked out how to fix it. For images to help, look at the **bottom** of this post.

On your PC, navigate to your file explorer. Now, on the **bar at the top**, copy and paste this: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\`. When you are brought to this page, find the search bar, and type in: `hosts`. This should bring up a file. Make sure that you permanently delete this, and no need to restart your launcher. It should connect now.

Images to help:

[[image: C:\Windows\System32\drivers][2]]

[image: HOSTS in search bar]

Comment: I'd be wary of deleting the `hosts` file - this is a system file. If you think your hosts file is the issue, you'd be better off [resetting it to default instead](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default)

Answer (score -1):

If you have tried everything and non of them have worked then you should just back up your world saves and resource packs, delete everything related to minecraft (apart from the saves and packs you backed up) and try re-installing it. If that doesn't work then try and contact Mojang.

I hope this helped, and if it did happy mining.